# Difference between Euclidean space and inner product space?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Is it that Inner product space can have infinite dimensions?

Comment: Hilbert space is an example of a complete inner product space. Hilbert spaces can be infinite dimensional.

Comment: This depends on the context. For example, consider the vector space $X := \mathbb{P}^k(0,1)$ of polynomials of degree less than or equal $k$ on the interval $[0,1]$, with integration $(p,q) = \int_0^1 p(x)q(x)dx$ as the inner product. As a finite dimensional vector space, $X$ is isomorphic (but not isometric) to $\mathbb{R}^{k+1}$. but yet that is not a natural way to think about it. The inner product in the coefficient basis is quite different than the dot product. Many people would be uncomfortable calling $X$ "euclidean" space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term Euclidian space is usually used only for spaces $\mathbb R^n$ for $n\in\mathbb N$. On the other hand, an inner product space is any vector space with a vector product.

A vector product induces a metric on the space, but that does not mean each inner product space is $\mathbb R^n$, as there exist inner product spaces which are not complete, for example. There also exist complete inner product spaces which are not finite-dimensional.

Bottom line: The difference is that Euclidian spaces are only one example of inner product spaces which have plenty of properties that inner product spaces in general do not.

Answer (score 9):

"A finite dimensional real inner product space is called a Euclidean space."

From Introduction to Hilbert Spaces with Applications, Second Edition by L. Debnath and P. Mikusinski, 1999.  Page 92.

Comment: Nice and concise definition. I like it.

Answer (score 3):

The underlying field of a Euclidian space are the real numbers, $\mathbb R$. There are also complex spaces with inner products, like e.g. $\mathbb C^n$. The inner products on real spaces are bi-linear, while inner products on complex spaces are sesqui-linear, only.

Answer (score 2):

There is a fine difference in the structure which you want to underline. I understand the Euclidean space to be $\mathbb{R}^n$ but considered as an affine space with a (euclidean) metric. You don't need to have a distinguished point such as zero.